# How to load the the database result set into jeditorpane

Tags: java, mysql, swing, resultset, jeditorpane

How to load the database result set into `jeditorpane`. After inserting the result set, is it possible to change the alignment?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1):

You can have [HTML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) in your `JEditorPane`. If you convert your `ResultSet` into an HTML `<table>`, you can align it that way.